# C#: Not fully expanding environment variables?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, path, environment-variables

If you go to **Control Panel > Environment Variables** and look at your `PATH`, there will be parts that look like this:

```
...Toolkit\;%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin;C:\Program...
```

Other environment variables are 'embedded' in the `PATH`, in other words.

Now to my question. When I call `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")` from my C# application, it automatically expands the variables in the `PATH`, so that segment will look like this:

```
...Toolkit\;C:\Users\James\.dnx\bin;C:\Program...
```

and when my program modifies the `PATH` and saves it back via `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", ...)`, **the sub-variable is erased** and `%USERPROFILE%` is replaced with `C:\Users\James`.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

PATH variable should not contain environment variables inside, because it is a REG_SZ registry value, not a expandable REG_EXPAND_SZ value.

The solution is don't add variables in PATH value and don't use `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` for PATH variable.

Anyways I'll answer to your question.

> How can I prevent this from happening?

Simply replace "%" chars for a non-expandable symbol or add another symbol like "_" char, this way you ensure variables are not expanded.

```
string value =
    Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path").Replace("%", "%_"));
```

Comment: They're complaining that *GetEnvironmentVariable* already performs the expansion.

Comment: @Joey Yep, pretty much.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this answer, because when I first got my computer and looked at the `PATH`, it already had some variables embedded like `%SystemRoot%\System32`. I'll accept it though.

Comment: Never mind, found a better solution that I'll post soon.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments, but I just looked inside regedit and PATH *is* a REG_EXPAND_SZ value, so this answer is wrong...